# Mesh has lines with rigify

Tags: mesh, rigify

My mesh is distorted when I use rigify and pose. How can I get rid of the lines that show up?
This happens in every project that I create.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the model so that we can trouble shoot it?

Comment: original: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kCWn2jjrpoyg5kUKjMCMriY0xTn2A1Eh/view?usp=sharing
retop: https://pasteall.org/blend/49f05cdd67464fdf9abade36a5ee4fb4

Answer (score 0):

The mesh is too dense for animating: theese lines are the boundaries of the weight paint zones, you could use the  weight paint smooth brush to soften them all, but it would be difficult and tedious.

The correct way is to do a retopology with a much smaller amount of vertices (10-50 K should work), then bake all small details onto a Normal Map, and rig this new MediumPoly mesh.

Comment: I did an auto retop. The lines are better but they are still there. What else can I do? 

original: drive.google.com/file/d/1kCWn2jjrpoyg5kUKjMCMriY0xTn2A1Eh/… retop: pasteall.org/blend/49f05cdd67464fdf9abade36a5ee4fb4

Comment: Yeah, that does look strange. I've seen it before but I can never put my finger on the exact cause.